# Spark High Availability

Tags: apache-spark

I`m using spark 1.2.1 on three nodes that run three workers with slave configuration and run **daily** jobs by using:

```
./spark-1.2.1/sbin/start-all.sh

//crontab configuration:
./spark-1.2.1/bin/spark-submit --master spark://11.11.11.11:7077 --driver-class-path home/ubuntu/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.1-FAT.jar --class "$class" "$jar"
```

I want to keep spark master and slave workers available at all times, and even if it fail I need it to be restarted like a ***service*** (like cassandra does).

Is there any way to do it?

**EDIT:**

I looked into start-all.sh script and it is only contains the setup for start-master.sh script and start-slaves.sh script.
I tried to create a **supervisor** configuration file for it and only get the below errors:

```
11.11.11.11: ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.12 port 22: No route to host
11.11.11.13: org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 14627. Stop it first.
11.11.11.11: ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.12 port 22: No route to host
11.11.11.12: ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.13 port 22: No route to host
11.11.11.11: org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 14627. Stop it first.
11.11.11.12: ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.12 port 22: No route to host
11.11.11.13: ssh: connect to host 11.11.11.13 port 22: No route to host
11.11.11.11: org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 14627. Stop it first.
```

Comment: you'll need a mesos or chronos cluster, or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools like monit and supervisor (or even systemd) that can monitor and restart failed processes.

Comment: but spark start-all.sh is a bash script that run the slaves, if I will use supervisor to keep it up - it will not know about the slave processes it had opened and if it fail and supervisor try to set it up again- I will have slave threads still running...

Comment: Don't use start-all.sh then)) What I'd probably do is manage the start/stop of spark daemons on each node independently. Spark has a spark-daemon.sh script to start a specific process (master or worker) on a specific node. So, you'd have supervisord installed on each node and it would manage spark daemons only on that specific node.